# How do I update value of a VARCHAR variable on it's particular index in P-SQL?

Tags: oracle, varchar

I am working on a program that swaps lowercase letters into uppercase and uppercase to lower in Oracle SQL. I want to update letter at index I but have no idea how to.

Comment: Please provide some sample code and data to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option (could be shortened by putting `case` expression directly into `retval`, but this is easier to follow (especially when another step - swap at index - gets involved.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test(par_string in varchar2, par_index in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    letter varchar2(1);
  5    retval varchar2(20);
  6  begin
  7    for i in 1 .. length(par_string) loop
  8      letter := substr(par_string, i, 1);
  9      letter := case when lower(letter) = letter then upper(letter)
 10                     else lower(letter)
 11                end;
 12      retval := retval || letter;
 13    end loop;
 14    return retval;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test('abCdE', 2) from dual;      --> expecting ABcDe

F_TEST('ABCDE',2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABcDe
```

Including the index:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test(par_string in varchar2, par_index in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    letter varchar2(1);
  5    retval varchar2(20);
  6  begin
  7    for i in 1 .. length(par_string) loop
  8      letter := substr(par_string, i, 1);
  9      letter := case when i = par_index then
 10                       case when lower(letter) = letter then upper(letter)
 11                            else lower(letter)
 12                       end
 13                else letter
 14                end;
 15      retval := retval || letter;
 16    end loop;
 17    return retval;
 18  end;
 19  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test('abCdE', 2) from dual;      --> only 2nd letter should change case: b --> B 
                                               --> so expected result is aBCdE

F_TEST('ABCDE',2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aBCdE

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT**]

If you want to replace character at certain position with something else, here's a simple example (improve it, if you want):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_char
  2    (par_string in varchar2, par_Index in number, par_char in varchar2)
  3  return varchar2
  4  is
  5    retval varchar2(20);
  6  begin
  7    retval := substr(par_string, 1, par_index - 1) || par_char ||
  8              substr(par_string, par_index + 1);
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_char('abcde', 3, 'x') res1,
  2         f_char('abcde', 1, 'y') res2,
  3         f_char('abcde', 5, 'z') res3
  4  from dual;

RES1       RES2       RES3
---------- ---------- ----------
abxde      ybcde      abcdz

SQL>
```

Comment: That's a great explanation, however I'd also love to know how can i simply alter VARCHAR varable like for example var_name[1] = 'a'.

Comment: @Kefest1 Oracle does not support that syntax. You would need to use sub-string functions.

Comment: Okay, but is there a function to do that specificly? Something like SET(INDEXAT, My_CHARACTER)

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: Okey I think that it's all I need to know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `TRANSLATE` function to swap all characters in a string from lower-to-upper case and vice-versa:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET your_column = TRANSLATE(
                    your_column,
                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                  );
```

If you only want to swap a specific character then split the string and only swap the characters on a particular substring.

For example, if you only want to swap the 3rd character:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET your_column = SUBSTR(your_column, 1, 2)       -- First 2 characters
                  || TRANSLATE(
                       SUBSTR(your_column, 3, 1), -- Third character
                       'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                       'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                     )
                  || SUBSTR(your_column, 4);      -- The remaining string
```

---

If you want a PL/SQL function then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION swap_case(
  i_string IN VARCHAR2,
  i_start  IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  i_length IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_length PLS_INTEGER := COALESCE(i_length, LENGTH(i_string));
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBSTR(i_string, 1, i_start - 1)
      || TRANSLATE(
           SUBSTR(i_string, i_start, v_length),
           'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
           'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
         )
      || SUBSTR(i_string, i_start + v_length);
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT swap_case('Hello World'),
       swap_case('Hello World', 3, 6)
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SWAP_CASE('HELLOWORLD') | SWAP_CASE('HELLOWORLD',3,6) |
| --- | --- |
| hELLO wORLD | HeLLO wOrld |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jFyvzelN)